# How can I count number of elements after query?

Tags: jq

I have a query:

```
.modules[].resources | select (.[]!=null)
```

and after it I have got:

```
{ somestuff } { somestuff } { somestuff }
```

when I add legth after all:

```
.modules[].resources | select (.[]!=null) | length
```

I have got:

```
1 1 1
```

but I need to count elements, so I need 3 in an output. How can I implement it ?

In fact it would be very useful to create an array from the first query output to operate with it furthure

```
[ { somestuff } , { somestuff } , { somestuff } ]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can put the results of the query into a list and get the length of this list:

```
[ .modules[].resources | select (.[]!=null) ] | length
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you indicated it would be very useful to create an array from the first query output, what you probably want to use here is [map](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)).

Let's assume your data is something like 
the data from this question: [jq: search by value from another array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181542/jq-search-by-value-from-another-array-element)

```
{
  "modules": [
    {
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "openstack_compute_instance_v2",
          "primary": {
            "id": "5edfe2bf-94df-49d5-8118-3e91fb52946b",
            "attributes": {
              "name": "jumpbox"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2",
          "primary": {
            "attributes": {
              "instance_id": "5edfe2bf-94df-49d5-8118-3e91fb52946b",
              "floating_ip": "10.120.241.21"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

with this data your filter

```
   .modules[].resources 
 | select (.[]!=null)    #< do you really want this `[]` ?
```

would produce two copies of the entire `.resources` array.  What you may want instead is

```
   .modules[].resources 
 | map(select(.!=null))
```

which will give you an array

```
[
  {
    "type": "openstack_compute_instance_v2",
    "primary": {
      "id": "5edfe2bf-94df-49d5-8118-3e91fb52946b",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "jumpbox"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2",
    "primary": {
      "attributes": {
        "instance_id": "5edfe2bf-94df-49d5-8118-3e91fb52946b",
        "floating_ip": "10.120.241.21"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

to get the length, just add length:

```
  .modules[].resources
| map(select(.!=null))
| length
```

in this example giving

```
2
```

Because `map(f)` is defined as `[ .[] | f ]` the above filter is really

```
  .modules[].resources
| [
      .[]
    | select(.!=null)
  ]
| length
```

In this form you can clearly see the construction of the intermediate array.

Note also that jq provides a built-in [values](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#arrays,objects,iterables,booleans,numbers,normals,finites,strings,nulls,values,scalars) filter which is defined as `select(.!=null)` so this example could be further simplified to just

```
  .modules[].resources
| map(values)
| length
```

Comment: Unfortinatly it didn't helps. I suppose because your suggestion about array structure is wrong. It is little bit more complex and there is ampy arrays there so why I used (.[]!=null)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned at [jq: count nest object values which satisfy condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120333/jq-count-nest-object-values-which-satisfy-condition)

the best solution (e.g. because it does not involve construction of an intermediate array) would be to use `count`, defined as follows:

> def count(s): reduce s as $i (0; .+1);

With this definition, you should be able simply to wrap `count(...)` around your query since it produces a stream:

```
count(.modules[].resources | select (.[]!=null))
```

Or maybe you want something closer to:

```
count(.modules[].resources | objects)
```